# Combine different columns from different data frames based on another columns index R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

So I have three data frames we will call them a,b,c
within each data frame there are columns called 1,2,3,4 with 54175 rows of data

Column 1 has id names that are the same in each data frame but not necessarily in the same order

Columns 2,3,4 are just numeric values

I want to pull out all the information from column 2 for a,b,c based on ID from column 1 so each values for a,b,c will correlate to the correct ID

I tried something like

```
m1 <- merge(A[,'2'], b[,'2'], c[,2'], by='1')
```

I get this error

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does the number of different ids equal the number of rows?

Comment: First by should  be a column name or column index. What do you mean by "1"?

Comment: Also, I think you need to do this two-at-a-time. From `?merge`: "Merge two data frames...". I don't think it works for three at once.

Comment: Bigger problem, is that the `by` column needs to be in the data.frames you merge. When you give `A[,'2']` to `merge`, `merge` only sees the column named `"2"`, so telling it to do it `by="1"` is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `merge` two times:

```
merge(merge(a[1:2], b[1:2], by = "1"), c[1:2])
```

or `Reduce` with `merge`:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "1"), list(a[1:2], b[1:2], c[1:2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple problems:

- Merge works two-at-a-time, no more.
- You need to have the `by` column in the data.frames that are merged.

Fix these like this:

```
m1 <- merge(A[,c("1", "2")], B[,c("1", "2")])
m2 <- merge(m1, C[, c("1", "2")])
```

Then `m2` should be the result you're looking for.

As an aside, it's pretty weird to use column names that are just characters of numbers. If they're in order, just use column indices (no quotes), and otherwise put something in them to indicate that they're names not numbers, e.g., R's default of `"V1", "V2", "V3"`. Of course, the best is a meaningful name, like `"id", "MeasureDescription", ...`

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge them 2 at a time:

```
a<-data.frame(sample(1:100,100),100*runif(100),100*runif(100),100*runif(100))
colnames(a)<-1:4
b<-data.frame("C1"=sample(1:100,100),"C2"=100*runif(100),"C3"=100*runif(100),"C4"=100*runif(100))
colnames(b)<-1:4
c<-data.frame("C1"=sample(1:100,100),"C2"=100*runif(100),"C3"=100*runif(100),"C4"=100*runif(100))
colnames(c)<-1:4

f<-merge(a[,1:2],b[,1:2],by=(1))
f<-merge(f,c[,1:2],by=(1))
colnames(f)<-c(1,"A2","B2","C2")
head(f)

1       A2       B2       C2
1 1 54.63326 39.23676 28.10989
2 2 10.10024 56.08021 69.44268
3 3 45.02948 14.69028 22.44243
4 4 90.50883 33.61303 98.00917
5 5 13.80767 80.93382 77.22679
6 6 80.72241 27.22139 51.34516
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to answer this question is:

```
m1 <- merge(A[,'2'], b[,'2'], c[,2'], by='1')
```

should be by=(1)

```
m1 <- merge(A[,'2'], b[,'2'], c[,2'], by=(1))
```

only when you want to merge by a column name, you need single quotes, for example:

```
m1 <- merge(A[,'2'], b[,'2'], c[,2'], by='ID')
```